# What is the difference between `sudo` and `become` for privilege escalation?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

## Is either best practice & what's the difference between them?

I found two ways that were mentioned on GitHub to run playbooks as a privileged on Ansible.

The `sudo: True` was less frequent, but I'm new to Ansible so I don't know if that makes any difference.

### The two ways I found:

#### become: yes / become: True

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes
```

#### sudo: True

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  sudo: True
```

Is there any difference in the way in which the commands / playbook is executed?

Is either recommended?

I am confused as to which one should be used and why.

---

Links to the GitHub repository files for both options below:

#### become: yes

https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-for-devops/blob/master/security/main.yml

#### sudo: True

https://github.com/enginyoyen/ansible-best-practises#3-keep-your-plays-simple

Comment: `sudo` is the old name of `become`. I don't know when it changed exactly, but very long ago.

Comment: [Here they say _"before 1.9"_](https://ansible-docs.readthedocs.io/zh/stable-2.0/rst/become.html#become) knowing that we are now on the version 2.12 and that [the version 2.9 was discontinued end of last year](https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/ansible-engine), this tells you a bit how long ago this was.

Comment: So, in short, nowadays, use `become: true`. [_Playbooks using privilege escalation should always use "become*" options rather than the old su*/sudo* options._](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/docs/docsite/rst/porting_guides/porting_guide_2.0.rst#deprecated)

Comment: Although you did not get an error, either because you are using an outdated version of ansbile or because you simply did not try it yet, `sudo` has been deprecated long ago as indicated in the duplicate.